# Developer Story - "Only show personal statement to employers" checkbox not working in traditional view

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

There is a "Only show your personal statement to employers" checkbox on the personal statement that I have ticked.

This only works on the new developer story view - if you have a look at my profile and switch it into traditional view, you'll see a statement there, but I have the box ticked.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting the issue, it's been fixed!

Hiding your personal statement now works for both traditional and story view.